# Form on landing page is hacked

Tags: php, html, forms

A hosting site I use was breached and a landing page form is hacked.  The hack does not affect my other domains or their forms.

I have reset .httaccess, swapped out the email address I use for the form, changed the PHPMAILER_master with the original, and put in a honeypot script.  The hacks, bogus info coming to the email address on form, stops for a bit then continues in 3 to 2 minute intervals.

Comment: That means there's a backdoor somewhere, or several. Wipe the whole thing and restore from a backup, or otherwise audit every file.

Comment: @com.on.ist Sorry, but please use the English language here on SO. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know it is no longer safe to use the PHPMailer.
What does hacked mean? Is someone sending emails by targeting your script? If someone had access to your server, you must change ALL passwords and delete ALL files and replace them with a backup. (no backup? no mercy.)

Comment: Thank you all, I will delete the site rebuild and put it on another domain.   Hacked means that I am getting a continuous deluge of bogus emails from my landing page form, at the end of each email where I had a text field for random comments, there is always a link to a crypto web page.  Thanks

Comment: @com.on.ist If you say PHPMailer is no longer safe, what mailer is, please?

Comment: @dloj33 I'm not shure about the security. But last time i used PHPmailer my hoster deleted the file because of malware. I use Wordpress or Google-Forms now. But you can find some alternatives for PHPmailer here: https://php.libhunt.com/phpmailer-alternatives

Comment: What reasons do you have to assume your form is **hacked** instead of just getting **spammed**?

Comment: @Markus I thought it was hacked because it kept continuing regardless of what I did..  I will look at PHPMailer alternatives.

Comment: It should be easy enough to confirm if the mailer script on your server is still intact by comparing it with a known good version. If it is, then your issue is with the fact that the code is exploitable, or just not spam proof. Are you using the latest version of PHPMailer?

Comment: @Markus AO thanks for the question.  No I am not using the latest version of PHPMailer, let me update it and see what I get.  Thanks

Comment: I found out it is the form that is spammed.  That is why when I tool the PHPMailer out it still sent spammed mail.  It did it again and I took the index.php,, with the form out and  it stopped.

Comment: Well it still continued.  Seems when I even put everything on a sub domain it still sends the spammed emails.  I am getting quite an education.  I am at a loss.